# FXML in obfuscated JavaFX JAR can't find Controller class

Tags: deployment, ant, javafx-2, obfuscation, fxml

I am obfuscating my javafx application jar using `Proguard 4.8` and obfuscated jar is showing some classes missing into the jar. The missing classes are all the controller classes of FXML. What's wrong with this step in `build.xml` that Obfuscates the application JAR with additional two utilities jar?

```
<target name="Ofuscating" depends="CreatingJars" >
    <taskdef resource="proguard/ant/task.properties" classpath="${WorkingFolder}/proguard.jar" />
    <proguard>
        -dontusemixedcaseclassnames
        -printmapping proguard.map
        -dontshrink
        -dontoptimize
        -dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
        -dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
        <!--flattenpackagehierarchy ''-->
        -libraryjars "${java.home}/lib/rt.jar"
        -libraryjars "${java.home}/lib/javaws.jar"
        -libraryjars "${env.JAVA_HOME}/lib/ant-javafx.jar"
        -libraryjars "${env.JREFX_HOME}/lib/jfxrt.jar"          
        -libraryjars ${WorkingFolder}/libs/BareBonesBrowserLaunch.jar
        :
        :
        -libraryjars ${WorkingFolder}/CustomJars/Lib.jar 
        -injars ${WorkingFolder}/${app.name}.jar
        -injars ${WorkingFolder}/CustomJars/Verifier.jar(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)
        -injars ${WorkingFolder}/CustomJars/Utility.jar(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)
        -outjars ${WorkingFolder}/Obfuscated.jar
        -ignorewarnings
        -keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,LocalVariable*Table,*Annotation*,Synthetic,EnclosingMethod
        -adaptresourcefilecontents **.fxml,**.properties,META-INF/MANIFEST.MF,images/*.jar,publicCerts.store,production.version
        -keepclassmembernames class * {
            @javafx.fxml.FXML *;
        } 
        -keepclasseswithmembers public class com.javafx.main.Main, com.product.main.EntryFX, net.license.LicenseEntryPoint {
            public *; public static *;
        }
        -keep class * extends org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler
        -keepclassmembers class * extends org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler {
            private *;
                public *;
        }
    </proguard>
</target>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.fxml` files have strings with exact names of the controller class.

```
<Scene width="550" height="550"
    fx:controller="fxmltableview.FXMLTableViewController" 
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
```

You need to either exclude controllers from obfuscating or find out their new names and update `.fxml` files in obfuscated jar.